# how to add image into QGraphicsScene class by using pixmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview

Here i created a grid in the Q Graphics Scene class and i want to add a image in to each cell in the grid, so can you please help me. how can i add the image in each cell of the grid

```
class QS(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QS, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # self.grview = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('pradeep.jpg'))
        self.grview.setScene(self.scene)



        print "Inserted in QS col = {}, row = {}".format(X,Y)

        width = X * Setting.WIDTH
        height = Y * Setting.HEIGHT
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height)

        self.setItemIndexMethod(QtGui.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)

        for x in range(0,X+1):
            xc = x * Setting.WIDTH
            self.addLine(xc,0,xc,height)
            self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('pradeep.jpg'))
            # self.addPixmap(self.pixmap)


        for y in range(0,Y+1):
            yc = y * Setting.HEIGHT
            self.addLine(0,yc,width,yc)
            self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('pradeep.jpg'))
            # self.addPixmap(self.pixmap)

        # for x in range(0,X+1):
        #     for y in range(0,Y+1):
        #         self.addPixmap(0,y,imag)

class QV(QtGui.QGraphicsView, QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QV, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

my grid image is given bellow
[image]

Comment: Do you want to interact with the item or do you just want it to be a background image?

Comment: I don't want background image sir, i want to add image into each and every cell in grid,  i tried so hard many ways but i didn't get

Comment: okay, and the mesh you want to be a background image or are you going to move the lines?

Comment: I think you have not understood my question, being a background image can also draw in the cell but the disadvantage is that you can not move with the mouse but the advantage is that there is a lower cost, so I ask you.

Comment: yes sir i want background image

Comment: When you say: *yes sir i want like that* I do not understand you, in my answer I will show you several options and you will use the one you want, is that ok ?, on the other hand I have answered another question of yours and I do not know if it served you, and if it served you do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: ok thq so much sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be interpreted in many ways so I will show several options:

**1.** If you are not going to interact with the items as for example you do not want to move it, select it, rotate it, etc. then it is not necessary to use an item, the best in that case is to use `drawBackground()` since an item consumes more resources than a simple painted.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Setting:
    WIDTH = 80
    HEIGHT = 80

X, Y = 7, 5


class QS(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QS, self).__init__(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, X * Setting.WIDTH, Y * Setting.HEIGHT), parent)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        width = X * Setting.WIDTH
        height = Y * Setting.HEIGHT

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(width, 0))
        for _ in range(Y+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(0, Setting.HEIGHT)

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(0, height))
        for _ in range(X+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(Setting.WIDTH, 0)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("pradeep.png").scaled(Setting.WIDTH, 
            Setting.HEIGHT, 
            QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        p = QtCore.QPointF()
        for i in range(X):
            p = QtCore.QPointF(Setting.WIDTH*i, 0)
            for j in range(Y):
                painter.drawPixmap(p, pixmap)
                p += QtCore.QPointF(0, Setting.HEIGHT)


class QV(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    pass


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QS(self)
        view = QV(scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

**2.** If you want to interact with the images you could use `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, or a combination of both:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Setting:
    WIDTH = 80
    HEIGHT = 80

X, Y = 7, 5


class QS(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QS, self).__init__(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, X * Setting.WIDTH, Y * Setting.HEIGHT), parent)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("pradeep.png").scaled(Setting.WIDTH, 
            Setting.HEIGHT, 
            QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        p = QtCore.QPointF()
        for i in range(X):
            p = QtCore.QPointF(Setting.WIDTH*i, 0)
            for j in range(Y):
                it = self.addPixmap(pixmap)
                it.setPos(p)
                p += QtCore.QPointF(0, Setting.HEIGHT)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        width = X * Setting.WIDTH
        height = Y * Setting.HEIGHT

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(width, 0))
        for _ in range(Y+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(0, Setting.HEIGHT)

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(0, height))
        for _ in range(X+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(Setting.WIDTH, 0)


class QV(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    pass


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QS(self)
        view = QV(scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thq so much sir .. i am a beginner in pyqt4 but i want to learn all concepts can you pls suggest me a good book

Comment: @GouthamySri I do not know any book, I can suggest the QT docs although it is for C ++ the concepts are applied to PyQt, on the other hand if you are learning it is better that you learn PyQt5, PyQt4 is deprecated, I learned it to maintain old projects. On the other hand you have given me an upvote, and another thing is to mark it as correct, if you did I would thank you a lot, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour]. Finally, review the old SO answers, in many of them we explain the concepts.